# C# How to index arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, window

I want to add strings of a particular array in a combobox when I select item in another combobox and click a button. There are two arrays, S0 and S1. In S0 there are strings for syllabus of Mathemtics, and in S1 there are strings of syllabus for English.

My code:

```cs
for (int x = 0; x <= 1 ; x++)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == x)
    {
        foreach (string items in S+x  )
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(items);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) Your code does not compile, it has errors in this line `foreach (string items in S+x  )` and b) Your code is unclear to me, try using meaningful names in your variables so others can understand what are your trying to do.

Comment: i would highly recommend you to use `ComboBox.BeginUpdate` and `ComboBox.EndUpdate` Method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: S+x means to look for a variable called S, a variable called x and then add or concatinate their values, not to refer to a variable called S0 or S1 depending on the value of x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are planning to add additional subjects to the system, just use 2 separate foreach loops. If you want to make it expandible, use a 2 dimensional array of strings:

```
string[,] data;

//Fill data here using the first dimension for the subjects and the second for the different items in the subject. data[0,0] could be "Pythagoras" and data[1,0] "Shakespeare" for example.

for (int i=0; i<data.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<data.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(data[i, j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I didnt knew the Multidimensional arrays thanks this perfectly helped me

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, then you want to use the array S0 in case 1 where x==0 and S1 where x==1. if S0 and S1 are of same type e.g. string[] you could try something like

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 1 ; x++) 
{
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == x) 
   {
        var stringArray = x==0 ? S0 : S1; // select array S0 or S1 dependent on value of X
        foreach (string items in stringArray)
        {
             comboBox2.Items.Add(items);
        }
    }
}
```

and you may consider clearing the combobox2 items before adding new elements by adding the line

```
comboBox2.Items.Clear()
```

before the `foreach` loop